# Charging a battery with two sources, should I put them in series or parallel?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, solar-cell, generator, capacity

I would like to charge a battery using two sources (solar and a generator), should I put the two sources in series or parallel before the battery?

The battery is actually 3 batteries in series. Each of them is 1.2 V with a capacity of 2300 mAh.

Is it better to give the battery more current or more voltage?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use just the generator so you don't have to tolerate the variability of the PV.

If, when fully charged, each cell is at 1.2 volts, then you'll need a current-limited  source with greater than a 3.6 volt output to charge them, the current limit being determined by the cells' specifications.

If your generator can't generate more than 3.6 volts, then the PV should be connected in series with it.

Unless there's some compelling reason to do so, the PV and the generator shouldn't be connected in parallel, directly, since the one with the higher voltage will feed current into the one with the lower voltage, possibly starving the battery or increasing its charge time.

Also, since more voltage will cause more charge (current) to flow into the battery, it's better to arrange things so that the charger's output voltage only pushes the allowed current into the battery.  That is, neither excess voltage across nor current into the battery is a Good Thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect the charging sources in parallel.

To charge the battery, you need to provide the appropriate voltage, and no more current than the battery can accept.

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to only use one source at a time.

When it is dark, the PV panels will act like resistors, nullifying some of the power coming from the generator.

Also, if you consider putting them in series, remember that the panels are rated in how much current they can conduct.  For instance, if you have a 380 Watt panel in series with a 100 Watt panel, the 380 will be current-limited by the 100 panel.

If you put them in parallel, the panel may heat up from the current coming from the generator.  That's not good because it can damage the panel.

It would be best not to mix sources like described in the OP.  Set up a switch so you are using one or the other, but not both.